# How to make custom posts in WordPress for a dummy?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

What I want to know is, how can I implement my already made index.php file to apply custom posts to it. (See below)

What I want to accomplish:

```
Display all posts(already accomplished in index.php)
--> show normal post a.k.a 'Article' (already accomplished in index.php)

If category/or post type 'Aside' is used, don't apply a <a> tag, make title lighter(can figure it out in CSS)
-->show text for the 'Aside' marked post

If category/or post type 'Link' is used,  wrap title in <a> tag linking to a site(<-- how would I do that in WordPress?)  
-->show text for info about the link

If category/or post type 'Photo' is used, don't wrap title in a <a> tag
-->show attached image in post, and post text as a caption
```

I know this may look like a lot but I'm sure it's easily do-able.

Some source code may not help me all the way, so I have my index.php below to see if you can help me implement it into it:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <article>
            <!-- <p><span class="metaCat"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span></p> -->
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><span class="meta"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></span></p>
            <hr />
            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
</article>
        <hr class="big" />
    <?php endwhile; ?>



<?php else : ?>

    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If you can input the needed code into a workable index.php file you will get some well thought of brownie points!

Thanks and all help is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I finally see what you meant to do here. This is easily done using the `get_post_format()` function. Just replace the title here with:

```
<?php
$format = get_post_format(get_the_ID());
if ($format == 'link') { ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php  the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

The other bit about linking to a site though, I'm not sure how you want to accomplish that.  Are you referring to the blogroll?

The best option for the "link" post format, is to use a custom metabox/custom fields. Add your key as "URL" then type the address in the value field.

Use `get_post_meta()` to get the URL and use that instead of `the_permalink()` in the href.

Comment: I didn't bother answering in length because most of the topic was covered over at forrst.  It wouldn't take someone much to take what was written there and adapt it to their needs...  much less vote up the correct responses to their query.  I digress - as the first expectation was shattered so shall the second.  Your response is accurate but is missing the part about the post format being a link to an outside uri.  (This would require some get_post_custom(get_the_ID()) shenanigans).

Comment: As for the URL part... What I'm trying to accomplish is what is already done on Tumblr, basically. Have a link of a site/article to be a header of a post, like I'm sharing it through a post, with my written comments on it.